# How to enable adding special character to the password validation in regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using [this regular expression](http://www.rubular.com/r/jf69EWPQ4N) to validate password entry but this is not accepting any special character

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/
```

with this explanation:

```
/^
  (?=.*\d)          // should contain at least one digit
  (?=.*[a-z])       // should contain at least one lower case
  (?=.*[A-Z])       // should contain at least one upper case
  [a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}   // should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters
$/
```

How can I add the following to the expression as well?

```
/[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-]/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another positive-lookahead group if you want to ensure that there is a special character, and then add the special characters to the matching group:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-]{8,}$/
```

Comment: @Behseini Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: @Behseini no problem at all - I just wanted to make sure you had a working answer to your question.